# Pass a Component with props, inside a Higher-Order-Component (HOC)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I refer to this example of creating a React Higher Order Component, [taken from this article](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb).

I am struggling to fully comprehend & make use of this HOC.

```
interface PopupOnHoverPropType {
  hoverDisplay: string;
}

const WithPopupOnHover = <P extends object>(BaseComponent: React.FC<P>): React.FC<P & PopupOnHoverPropType> => ({ hoverDisplay, ...props }: PopupOnHoverPropType) => {

  const [displayMsg, setDisplayMsg] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const toggleDisplayMsg = () => {
    setDisplayMsg(displayMsg);
  };
  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={() => setDisplayMsg(true)}>
      <div className={`${hoverDisplay} popup`} onClick={toggleDisplayMsg}/>
      <BaseComponent {...props as P} />
    </div>
  )
};
```

Here is what my understanding of the above code is:

We define a HOC by the name of `WithPopupOnHover`,
which takes a React component (BaseComponent).
The BaseComponent comes with its props (referred as P)
which returns a new React component,
which takes props P & the props within `PopupOnHoverPropType`.

How do I use this HOC ?
The following attempt gives a typescript error that too many arguments are passed in:

```
  const enhanced = WithPopupOnHover(Modal);
  const m = Enhanced(a,b,c, "up");
```

The Modal React component has the following props structure:

```
const Modal: React.FC<{
  a: string;
  b(): void;
  c(locationData: customType): void;
}> = { ... }
```

Comment: Which is giving the error? `WithPopupOnHover`? or `Enhanced`, whatever that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just forgot the object brackets. React components all take a single props object argument.

```
const Enhanced = WithPopupOnHover(Modal);
const m = Enhanced({ a, b, c });
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. If I could ask, would you please review the explanation for the code & whether that is spot-on? Thanks

Comment: @Kayote Sure, but what "explanation for the code" do you want reviewed?

Comment: In the question above, just below the first block of code, where I start with: `Here is what my understanding of the above code is:` Thank you.

Comment: @Kayote Yes, that is essentially the idea. That article you linked does a good job of describing the types of HOCs.